# GitHub Desktop - Clone GitLab repository via HTTPS

Tags: https, gitlab, github-desktop

I'm working on Windows x64 and I'm using GitHub Desktop to clone a GitLab repository.

I'm having the below error, when trying to clone using HTTPS.
Note: I edited the URL address to not show the full URL.

"2020-06-03T08:50:46.479Z - error: [ui] `git -c credential.helper= clone --recursive --progress -- https://.../my-repository.git C:\Temp\GitHubDesktop-Repositories\my-repository` exited with an unexpected code: 128.
stderr:
Cloning into 'C:\Temp\GitHubDesktop-Repositories\my-repository'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://.../my-repository.git/'
(The error was parsed as 3: Authentication failed. Some common reasons include:

- You are not logged in to your account: see File > Options.
- You may need to log out and log back in to refresh your token.
- You do not have permission to access this repository.
- The repository is archived on GitHub. Check the repository settings to confirm you are still permitted to push commits.
- If you use SSH authentication, check that your key is added to the ssh-agent and associated with your account.)"

I was expecting to pop-up a window asking username and password so i can add the access token configured in GitLab.

I already did the following (but without sucess):

- Unistall GitHub Desktop
- Delete C:\Users\MyUser\Roaming\AppData\GitHub Desktop
- Confirm that Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager does not have any GitHub credential
- I'm not logged in GitHub, as the repository is from GitLab and no login is necessary (except from the necessary authentication i would like to configure "username and password/access token" that should pop-up when trying to clone).

When I used different computer (same Windows x64) i was able to configure correctly and indeed the username and password box appeared where I could add the details.

How can I manage to trigger that authentication window to update the username and password?
There is any file that I need to delete?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems is a bug and known issue in the software:

https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/9843

https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/9926

There will be a new release of GitHub Desktop. I will wait for the new release of the software to make sure this still not occurs.